# Is there an reason to use html as Facelets root instead of ui:composition?

Tags: jsf-2, facelets

I notice the Netbeans wizard to create a Facelets template client page gives the option to have either **html** or **ui:composition** as the document root for the page.

For time out of mind I have always used the **html** option, then kept using it for consistency.  Yet I realized that if I used **ui:composition** then I would save two levels of indentation for the body of my document.

The only reason to keep with **html** that I can remember is that I read somewhere that this format was hypothetically useful in an IDE somewhere.  However I have never encountered it.

Is there any reason to keep using **html** as the document root?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Facelets is supposed to be "designer friendly". The point of being able to have extra tags around the Facelets markup, and of features like the `jsfc` attribute or `ui:remove` is to let you write JSF pages that will render correctly when previewed in a web browser without having to actually run the application in a container. (E.g.: To make it easier to just tweak CSS for a single view.)

If you have no need for this, you can safely leave the extra clutter out.